# ruby version is not updating with rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv

It seems that RBENV_VERSION is set to 3.0.1

```
rbenv versions
system
2.6.5
2.7.3
* 3.0.1 (set by RBENV_VERSION environment variable)
```

but I cannot find the specific definition in to `.zshrc` file.
Where and when does this environment variable can be set?

Answer (score 1):

For projects you should be able to specify a ruby version with the `.ruby-version` file.

For the global version it can be in:

- `~/.rbenv/version`
- `RBENV_VERSION` variable

IF you've followed the install instructions you should have run `echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc` have rbenv should be handling this.

rbenv should then be reading the global version from the `~/.rbenv/version` file.